# Pass a function with bind() and parameters as a callback

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get a passing functions with parameters as callbacks in event listeners concept.

Here is my code:

```js
const scrollFunc = scrollY => {

 console.log(`scrolled on ${scrollY}`);

};

window.addEventListener('scroll', scrollFunc.bind(this, pageYOffset));
```

```css
html,
body {
  min-height: 110vh;
}
```

I just can't understand why it logs only `scrolled on 0` result and how to bind it properly.

I know that I can rewrite this function like this and it will work:

```
const scrollFunc = scrollY => {

    console.log(`scrolled on ${scrollY}`);

};

window.addEventListener('scroll', () => scrollFunc(pageYOffset));
```

but still I really need to understand how to fix the `.bind()` version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The major difference between your two code versions, is the time when the value of `pageYoffset` will be picked up for its use in the actual call of `scrollFunc`. In the version with `.bind`, that value is determined at the moment you execute `addEventListener`. In the other version, that value is determined only when the scroll event *triggers*.

You cannot really fix the `.bind` version, without abandoning `.bind` itself (which you already did successfully), because apparently `pageYoffset` does not yet have the appropriate value at the time you execute `.bind()`.

Answer (score 2):

`myfunc.bind(thisArg, 'hello')` will create a function with a lexical context `this` bound to `thisArg` (which is useless when using an arrow function) and for which the first argument will always be `"hello"`. So in your case the first argument will always be the value of `pageYOffset` which is `0`. Instead of taking it as argument just refer to its value inside your arrow function.

```
window.addEventListener("scroll" , () => console.log(pageYOffset));
```

Will do what you want.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I've told in the question that I can rewrite code with an arrow function, but still want to know how to make it work with .bind() if it possible

Comment: I thought that it was clear that there was no point using bind in the first place, especially in the case of an arrow function which does not have lexical context. My bad.